# Short animated film or movie where a boy travels to the future multiple times, each time seeing the Earth in a different stage of its life

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel, animation

The animation style if I remember right is similar to early to mid 2000s.

This boy travels through time and makes these stops as if going to all the different stages in the Earth's life. I believe he is unable to go back for some reason and he may have someone else with him. I know for certain of two times he travels through time: once to when Earth is in an ice age, and another that's so far in the future the humans are unrecognizable as human.

In the ice age one, I think the boy is panicking about how cold it is and wants to go forwards in time.

In the far-into-the-future-part, the Earth is a desert wasteland with nothing in sight besides the last human settlement. He makes friends with the future humans and gets help going back in time.

I watched this around 2011-2012. Would've been on Netflix or YouTube cause that's all I had access to at that time.
I've asked about this so many times on different websites and people, hopefully someone here knew what I'm talking about!

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies the animation you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. Thanks.

Comment: @LogicDictates - The system already gives them this prompt. I'm not sure what this additional prod adds, in terms of value. I can see some worth if it's there as a reminder (maybe a few days or weeks later), but these come across as a bit aggressive in pushing them to accept your answer, when it's posted less than 30 seconds after you've answered.

Comment: @Valorum - The prompt is intended to increase the odds of a correct answer being accepted, or an incorrect one being confirmed as such, both of which are surely good things. Waiting days or weeks to post such a prompt would likely be equivalent to closing the barn door after the horse has bolted in many cases, since first-time posters often don't stick around that long. Also, I did check to confirm that the OP hasn't yet taken the tour, in this case. Had they done so, I wouldn't have bothered with the prompt.

Comment: @LogicDictates - sorry, it just comes across as demanding. Each time I see it posted I'm thinking it reads like "***ACCEPT MY ANSWER NOW, NOW, NOW, NOW!"*** but in slightly politer wording.

Comment: @LogicDictates - I'm at the point of asking a meta question so we can get a reasonable consensus to stop you doing it.

Comment: @Valorum - You're ignoring the other aspect of the prompt; if my answer (or anyone else's) is _incorrect_, I'm asking the OP to confirm it, so that everyone _knows_ it's incorrect, and so that those who're inclined to do so will continue searching for the correct one. Without such confirmation, an incorrect answer that happens to be a good match to the description could put other users off from looking for alternative answers, decreasing the chances of the correct answer ever being posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is ***[Time Kid](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0395786/)*** (2003).

From IMDB:

> An adaptation of H.G Well's Time Machine for Nickleodon. Tom's scientist father, overwhelmed with grief over the loss of his wife, invents a time machine. He attempts to go in to the future to find a cure that he can take back in time to his wife, so that she might live. He never comes back, only his time machine. So Tom goes into the future to rescue his dad.

From [The Time Machine Wiki](https://timemachine.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Kid):

> In 19th Century New Jersey, a young boy named Tom Spender discovers his missing father's Time Machine with a note in the seat, saying that the father was stuck in the future and unable to return home. Tom boards the machine and explores the future, first visiting the year 2002 where he meets one of his descendants, and later the year 11,902.
>
> There, he meets a strange race of people- the Luman, who are a very simple, almost childlike folk who live in a domed community. They also have telekinetic powers. When Tom wonders where the food comes from, he discovers that it is provided by a second race, the Sub-Men. When the Luman come to get their food, the Sub-Men take a Luman in exchange.
>
> It seems that the Sub-Men are using electrical energy from the Luman's telekinetic powers to run their machines. Tom soon befriends a Sub-Man, Zorog, and convinces him that there are better ways for the two races to exist. The two soon rescue Lira, who has been captured, as well as Spender's father, Henry Spender.

The young protagonist, Tom, uses his father's time machine to jump to a period resembling an ice age at around the [16:44](https://youtu.be/dwTEi8KM8Rg?t=1004) mark in the video below, and decides to jump forward again very quickly, to escape the extreme cold. He then arrives in a desert-like region, where he meets a friendly race of people resembling the [Eloi](https://timemachine.fandom.com/wiki/Eloi) (from *[The Time Machine](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054387/)* (1960)), at around the [21:31](https://youtu.be/dwTEi8KM8Rg?t=1291) mark.